# Get value from Select Box on change

Tags: php, html

Im trying to retrieve the value from a select box after the selected index has been changed. I keep getting an undefined index variable.

The form reloads the page so that I can update a table elsewhere on the page. The options are filled from the results of an SQL query.

**The select box code.**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Select School</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="schoolSelect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php
        foreach ($faculty as $key) { ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $key['1']; ?>"><?php echo $key['1']; ?></option>

        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

**PHP used to retrive value**

```
if (isset($_POST['schoolSelect'])){
    $selectedSchool = $_POST['schoolSelect'];

    $result = executeUserSelect($sqlUserBySchool, $db, $_POST['schoolSelect']);
}
```

**EDIT**

var dump =

```
array (size=1)
  'schoolSelect' => string 'Plymouth Business School' (length=24)
```

Select box text =  Plymouth Business School

Thanks in advance

Tony

Comment: Two questions - what does the var_dump($_POST) display? and what does the HTML output in your <select>

Comment: @Duniyadnd great point - OP, at the top of your file put <?php print_r($_POST); ?> to always see what the $_POST variable has, and then view source on the page after it loads to see what the <option>s look like after rendered through PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the update - what's inside the executeUserSelect function?

Comment: Im calling the wrong select method. DOH! It works fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['schoolSelect'])){
    $selectedSchool = $_POST['schoolSelect'];

    echo $selectedSchool;
}
else {
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Select School</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="schoolSelect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php
        foreach ($faculty as $key) { ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $key['1']; ?>"><?php echo $key['1']; ?></option>

        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in case if I don't want to resubmit the form then how would I retrieve the selected value without using jQuery and pass it to php function.